# What's the range of this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Domain is <s>all</s> real numbers. $f(x) = \sqrt{x - 3}$. The book's answer is "all non negative real numbers". But this includes all values between 0 and 3. Squareroot of negative number doesn't exist in real number set.

Comment: The domain isn't all real numbers, as $\sqrt{-1 - 3} = 2i$ which is not real. Can you find say an $x$ such that $2 = \sqrt{x - 3}$? How about $-1 = \sqrt{x - 3}$? I think you're mixing up the definition of domain and range.

Comment: Yes, I did confuse.

Comment: Instead of editing the question title to add "Solved", you could answer your own question... :)

Comment: @okelvin: In fact, please do as J.M. suggests: write out your solution as an answer. Then you can later even accept it!

Answer (score 2):

Confused domain and image. Domain is [3, $+\infty$). Range is: what's the lowest value that the function can return? f(3) = 0, then the book's answer is right.